TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType when trying to call repair or getTotalEnergy
When I'm trying to when I'm trying to the below code, showing error as foldx_location as none but I'm already setting this path to access downloaded pyfoldx executable file. I'm using it in colab notebook and
os.environ['FOLDX_LOCATION'] = './path/to/foldx/'
from pyfoldx.structure import Structure
obj = Structure("pred", path=path) 
obj = obj.repair(verbose=False)

error message:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

@pyfoldx @python


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if error shows you which line makes problem then you could use print() to check what you have in variables. Maybe one of your variable has None instead of path.
